# UV grab/scale/rotate doesn't work

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I have a problem with grabbing uv maps in the UV Editing window. I can select an uv selecting a mesh in the Edit Mode, then when I'm trying to use move, scale  or rotate uv in the UV Editor, nothing happens. In case it was a bug, I've just downloaded the newest build and unfortunately still have the issue.
Does anybody know how to resolve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Came out that it's just a file error - I created a new file and appended my object.